# Bijections on $\mathbb{R}^n$ taking lines to lines

Tags: geometry

$\mathbb{R}^n$ be Euclidean inner product space. By a line in this space, we mean a coset of $1$-dimensional subspace of the vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$.

**Q.** If $f\colon\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ is a bijection which takes lines to lines, and $f(0)=0$, is $f$ necessarily a linear map?

The answer seems to me Yes; but I neither satisfied to prove it nor found a reference online.